# Div containers totaling 100% of the width are overflowing

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am trying to fill the whole width of a container using containers with percentage defined widths. However it looks like even when the containers total 100% of the width, they are still overflowing due to the space between the containers.

Here is a simple reproducible example, in which three select inputs of widths 35%, 35% and 30% overflow inside a well panel of 50% width (of the whole page):

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("My App"),
  br(),
  wellPanel(
    style = "width: 50%;",
    div(
      style = "width: 35%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;",
      selectInput("select1", "select 1 (35% width)", choices = 1:5)
    ),
    div(
      style = "width: 35%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;",
      selectInput("select2", "select 2 (35% width)", choices = 1:5)
    ),
    div(
      style = "width: 30%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;",
      selectInput("select1", "select 1 (30% width)", choices = 1:5)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have tried to access the property through the app's HTML code by inspecting it to no avail, as it tells me margins and paddings are 0 by default.

I do not want to remove the space between the div containers, but rather find a robust way to control it.

However, assuming that the whitespace is always of 4px, then I've found a way to solve the issue.

Let n be the number of inline div containers - 1 (so n = 2 in my case with three divs). Then the total whitespace width is n*4 px = 8px in my example and I can use `width: calc(35% - 8px);` for example.

Comment: You're better off using Grid of Flexbox for this kind of thing, rather than inline-block, as they give you much more control over layout and spacing.

Comment: @ralph.m thanks I was able to use Flexbox, my initial error trying this method was that the `display: flex;` commands were in each child container instead of one inside the parent container, so I discarded it. Looks perfect now thanks.